# Always getting false response from pdo update query

Tags: php

I'm trying to update my database but whenever i do like this

```
if($query){
echo 'executed';
}
else {
echo 'error';
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that query is successfully updating database but result in false response here is my code

```
 public static function updateItem($slug, $title, $description, $thumbnail, $preview, $main_file, $screenshot, $category, $amount, $review, $demo_url, $tags, $live, $video, $apc) {
        $db = new Database;
        $main_category = Login::encrypt_decrypt("decrypt", $apc);
        $sub_category = Login::encrypt_decrypt("decrypt", $category);
        $q = $db->updateRow("UPDATE items SET name = ?, description = ?, thumbnail = ?, main_file = ?, categories = ?, sub_category = ?, demo_url = ?, slug = ?, price = ?, reviewer_comment = ?, datetime = ?, status = ?, video_file = ?, item_tags_string = ?, preview_file = ?, screenshot_file = ?, live_file = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND temp_files != '' AND temp_file_real != '' AND status = ?", [$title, $description, $thumbnail, $main_file, $main_category, $sub_category, $demo_url, $slug, $amount, $review, Item::nowTime(), 'queue', $video, $tags, $preview, $screenshot, $live, Profile::getid(), 'temp']);
        if($q){
            echo 'good'; exit;
        }
        else {
            echo 'wrong'; exit;
        }
    }
```

This is my database connection code

```
public function __construct($username = "root", $password = "", $host = "localhost", $dbname = "market", $options = []) {
        $this->isConn = TRUE;
        try {
            $this->datab = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
            $this->datab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->datab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

here is update query function

```
public function updateRow($query, $params = []) {
        $this->insertRow($query, $params);
    }

public function insertRow($query, $params = []) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($params);
            return TRUE;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

can anyone tell me why I'm receiving false statement always

Comment: can you add the updateRow code ?

Comment: I have added updateRow code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updateRow function doesn't return anything so '$q' is empty.

```
public function updateRow($query, $params = []) {
    return $this->insertRow($query, $params);
}
```